# MediaCodec AV Sync when decoding

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, android-mediacodec, android-ffmpeg

All of the questions regarding syncing audio and video, when decoding using `MediaCodec`, suggests that we should use an "AV Sync" mechanism to sync the video and audio using their timestamps.

Here is what I do to achieve this:

I have 2 threads, one for decoding video and one for audio. To sync the video and audio I'm using `Extractor.getSampleTime()` to determine if I should release the audio or video buffers, please see below:

```java
//This is called after configuring MediaCodec(both audio and video)
private void startPlaybackThreads(){
    //Audio playback thread
    mAudioWorkerThread = new Thread("AudioThread") {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                try {
                    //Check info below
                    if (shouldPushAudio()) {
                        workLoopAudio();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    mAudioWorkerThread.start();

    //Video playback thread
    mVideoWorkerThread = new Thread("VideoThread") {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                try {
                    //Check info below
                    if (shouldPushVideo()) {
                        workLoopVideo();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    mVideoWorkerThread.start();
}

//Check if more buffers should be sent to the audio decoder
private boolean shouldPushAudio(){
    int audioTime =(int) mAudioExtractor.getSampleTime();
    int videoTime = (int) mExtractor.getSampleTime();
    return audioTime <= videoTime;
}
//Check if more buffers should be sent to the video decoder
private boolean shouldPushVideo(){
    int audioTime =(int) mAudioExtractor.getSampleTime();
    int videoTime = (int) mExtractor.getSampleTime();
    return audioTime > videoTime;
}
```

Inside `workLoopAudio()` and `workLoopVideo()` is all my `MediaCodec` logic (I decided not to post it because it's not relevant).

So what I do is, I get the sample time of the video and the audio tracks, I then check which one is bigger(further ahead). If the video is "ahead" then I pass more buffers to my audio decoder and visa versa.

This seems to be working fine - The video and audio are playing in sync.

---

<strike>**My question:**</strike>

<strike>I would like to know if my approach is correct(is this how we should be doing it, or is there another/better way)? I could not find any working examples of this(written in java/kotlin), thus the question.</strike>

---

### **EDIT 1:**

I've found that the audio trails behind the video (very slightly) when I decode/play a video that was encoded using `FFmpeg`. If I use a video that was not encoded using `FFmpeg` then the video and audio syncs perfectly.

The `FFmpeg` command is nothing out of the ordinary:

```
-i inputPath -crf 18 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast OutputPath
```

I will be providing additional information below:

I initialize/create `AudioTrack` like this:

```java
//Audio
mAudioExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
mAudioExtractor.setDataSource(mSource);
int audioTrackIndex = selectAudioTrack(mAudioExtractor);
if (audioTrackIndex < 0){
    throw new IOException("Can't find Audio info!");
}
mAudioExtractor.selectTrack(audioTrackIndex);
mAudioFormat = mAudioExtractor.getTrackFormat(audioTrackIndex);
mAudioMime = mAudioFormat.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);

mAudioChannels = mAudioFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT);
mAudioSampleRate = mAudioFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE);

final int min_buf_size = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(mAudioSampleRate, (mAudioChannels == 1 ? AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO : AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO), AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
final int max_input_size = mAudioFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE);
mAudioInputBufSize =  min_buf_size > 0 ? min_buf_size * 4 : max_input_size;
if (mAudioInputBufSize > max_input_size) mAudioInputBufSize = max_input_size;
final int frameSizeInBytes = mAudioChannels * 2;
mAudioInputBufSize = (mAudioInputBufSize / frameSizeInBytes) * frameSizeInBytes;

mAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
    mAudioSampleRate,
    (mAudioChannels == 1 ? AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO : AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO),
    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
    AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(mAudioSampleRate, mAudioChannels == 1 ? AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO : AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT),
    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

try {
    mAudioTrack.play();
} catch (final Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "failed to start audio track playing", e);
    mAudioTrack.release();
    mAudioTrack = null;
}
```

And I write to the `AudioTrack` like this:

```java
//Called from within workLoopAudio, when releasing audio buffers
if (bufferAudioIndex >= 0) {
    if (mAudioBufferInfo.size > 0) {
        internalWriteAudio(mAudioOutputBuffers[bufferAudioIndex], mAudioBufferInfo.size);
    }
    mAudioDecoder.releaseOutputBuffer(bufferAudioIndex, false);
}

private boolean internalWriteAudio(final ByteBuffer buffer, final int size) {
    if (mAudioOutTempBuf.length < size) {
        mAudioOutTempBuf = new byte[size];
    }
    buffer.position(0);
    buffer.get(mAudioOutTempBuf, 0, size);
    buffer.clear();
    if (mAudioTrack != null)
        mAudioTrack.write(mAudioOutTempBuf, 0, size);
    return true;
}
```

**"NEW" Question:**

The audio trails about 200ms behind the video if I use a video that was encoded using `FFmpeg`, is there a reason why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it is working now. I use the same logic as above, but now I keep a reference of the `presentationTimeUs` returned from `MediaCodec.BufferInfo()` before calling `dequeueOutputBuffer` to check if I should continue my video or audio work loop:

```java
// Check if audio work loop should continue
private boolean shouldPushAudio(){
    long videoTime = mExtractor.getSampleTime();
    return tempAudioPresentationTimeUs <= videoTime;
}
// Check if video work loop should continue
private boolean shouldPushVideo(){
    long videoTime = mExtractor.getSampleTime();
    return tempAudioPresentationTimeUs >= videoTime;
}

// tempAudioPresentationTimeUs is set right before I call dequeueOutputBuffer
// As shown here:
tempAudioPresentationTimeUs = mAudioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs;
int outIndex = mAudioDecoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(mAudioBufferInfo, timeout);
```

By doing this, my video and audio is synced perfectly, even with files that was encoded with `FFmpeg`(as mentioned in my edit above).

---

I ran into an issue where my video work loop didn't complete, this was caused by the audio reaching EOS before the video and then returning `-1`. So I changed my original `mVideoWorkerThread` to the following:

```java
mVideoWorkerThread = new Thread("VideoThread") {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            try {
                if (shouldPushVideo() || audioReachedEOS()) {
                    workLoopVideo();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};
mVideoWorkerThread.start();

private boolean audioReachedEOS() {
    return mAudioExtractor.getSampleTime() == -1;
}
```

So I use `audioReachedEOS()` to check if my audio `MediaExtractor` returns `-1`. If it does then it means that my audio is done, but my video is not, so I continue my video work loop until it is done.

This seems to be working as expected (when I only play/pause the video without seeking). I had another issue with seeking, but I will not elaborate on this.

I will release my application as is and update this answer when I run into problems.